# Javascript/ React.js equivalent of Ruby .select{ |x| condition }

Tags: javascript, for-loop, reactjs

I've written the following function in javascript (React.j) that makes use of a for loop:

```
getOpponentTeam: function(playerTeamId){
  var matches = this.state.matches;
  var player_team = this.state.player.team.name
  for (i in matches){
    if (matches[i].home_team_id == playerTeamId){
      var result = player_team + " vs. " + this.getTeamName( matches[i].away_team_id )
    }
    else if (matches[i].away_team_id == playerTeamId){
      var results = this.getTeamName( matches[i].home_team_id ) + " vs. " + player_team
    }
    else {
      var result = "Not playing"
    }
    return result
  };
},
```

The problem is that, the way the for loop is working, most of the times it returns "Not playing" even though "matches" contains data that meets the conditions. This is because the for loop is short circuiting.

Is there a way to cut down the matches array like you can do in ruby by saying matches.select{ |x| some condition }?

Comment: like `Array.prototype.filter` or `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: is `matches` an array or an object?

Comment: How do you expect your loop to loop when you return right out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code.

**1. Wrong use of a for loop.**

You're looping through an array as if it's an object.  You'll need to use the following implementation:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (matches[i].home_team === playerTeamId) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

**2. You're returning on the first iteration**

As pointed out by Nit in the comments, you're returning on the first loop, so it cannot continue.

**3. To kind of answer your intended question**

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but I think you may be asking for the filter operation in [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I followed your suggestion and it worked perfectly!